# no show number is persian?

Tags: fonts, web-design

I downloaded the minister [font fanavari](https://fontjo.com/%D9%81%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AA-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C-fanavari/) from this link and pressed change to create this post ...
but the numbers in Latin are not displayed for me in Persian.
What is the solution?

Comment: Sorry, but it's difficult to understand what your question is. Are you having a problem with the font that you downloaded or this site? Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has probably nothing to do with fonts, but I would guess that you are confused by the Persian keyboard layout.

With the Persian layout you can type Arabic digits like this:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> => 1

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> => 2

etc.

HTH

Comment: tnx [link](https://delsamusic.com/cat/music/)